# Sql Server SELECT statement with a "bad" date condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

Say, if I need to select records from the database where the date field is in a particular time frame. The select query would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Date] >= @RangeBegin AND [Date] <= @RangeEnd;
```

But I have a little condition when the Date field might be empty or invalid. In that case the date value should be taken from @DefaultDate.

How do you put all this into SQL?

Comment: You'll have to define invalid. What datatypes are @RangeBegin and Date? And empty means NULL?

Comment: What is the type of the field `[Date]`? DateTime or String ? The parameter `@DefaultDate` is for filtering data, or this is the data you need for output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say that the date can be invalid I assume you have stored dates as varchar.
You can use [isdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) to check if the date is valid.

```
select case isdate([Date]) 
         when 1 then cast([Date] as datetime)
         else @DefaultDate 
       end as [Date]
from MyTable
where case isdate([Date]) 
        when 1 then cast([Date] as datetime)
        else @DefaultDate 
      end between @RangeBegin and @RangeEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how a Date field might be invalid.
But, for null value, you can do the following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE (     [Date] IS NOT NULL 
        AND [Date] >= @RangeBegin AND [Date] <= @RangeEnd
      )
OR    (     [Date] IS NULL 
        AND @DefaultDate >= @RangeBegin AND @DefaultDate <= @RangeEnd
      )
```

Comment: The 'date field' might be stored as a varchar for whatever reason in that case I would extend that `[Date] IS NULL` to be `([Date] IS NULL OR ISDATE([Date]) = 0)` and also change the `[Date] IS NOT NULL` to be `[Date] IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE([Date]) = 1` that way you make sure you're checking valid dates. However if you're storing dates as strings you're doing it wrong, unless your data comes from an import and you're trying to perform data migration.

Comment: `SELECT *` will take values from `[Date]` field whatever the condition is. You have to use `CASE` clause in order to return `@DefaultDate`. P.S. the question is not clear where the `@DefaultDate` should be used: in the condition or in the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ([Date] IS NULL) THEN @DefaultDate ELSE [Date] END AS [Date]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE ([Date] >= @RangeBegin AND [Date] <= @RangeEnd) OR ([Date] IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

select case when isdate([Date]) = 0 then @DefaultDate else [Date] end
from ...
where Date between @RangeBegin and @RangeEnd or isdate([Date]) = 0

Case statement in the where clause should be avoid whenever possible.